# Visual Studio 2013 Pro installation completed with error, not all features installed correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My Visual Studio 2013 Pro installation completed with below error (image below).
How can I install the remaining features which gave error. I have tried repair but after its completion I again received the same error. Just a clarification, I am installing this on a brand new laptop having Windows 10 Pro.

[image]

*Please do not give guess based answers as installing VS is time consuming.*

Comment: Have you reviewed the "common issues and workarounds" or "examined the log file"?  If you did, what did you find out?

Comment: I am not capable of understanding microsoft log files having 4K-5K lines.

Comment: It is something of an avalanche of data!  There are some tricks you can use to try and zero in on the relevant stuff.  Try searching for the word "Error" or "Failure".  Not every "Error" or "Failure" will be relevant to your problem but it does reduce the number of lines to read.  If that doesn't help try searching for " 0x8" since most failure HRESULTs start with 8 when listed in hex.  Again, not all FAILED(hr) are necessarily a problem.  Finally, you can try looking for "SQL"  That should let you skip over the log entries pertaining to other components installed prior to your failure.

Comment: Tried finding error related terms in log file, but it gave no clue.

Comment: There's a Microsoft Knowledge Base article on Common Visual Studio 2013 setup issues.  None of the issues described seem directly relevant but the [More Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2899270/visual-studio-2013-setup-common-issues-and-workarounds#furtherhelp) section suggests posting your Visual Studio installation log file to the [Visual Studio Setup and Installation forum](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=250777)